# How to read specific tags using XML2

Tags: r, xml2

#### Problem

I am trying to get all of the url's in https://www.ato.gov.au/sitemap.xml (N.B it's a ~9mb file) using xml2. Any pointers appreciated.

#### My attempt

```
library("xml2")
data1 <- read_xml("https://www.ato.gov.au/sitemap.xml")
xml_find_all(data, ".//loc")
```

I'm not getting the output I need:

> {xml_nodeset (0)}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using `xml2` but I was able to get it using `rvest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.ato.gov.au/sitemap.xml"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes("loc") %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need all the urls in dataframe you can use below code:

```
library(XML)
library(xml2)
library(httpuv)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
url <- "https://www.ato.gov.au/sitemap.xml"
xData <- getURL(url)
doc <- xmlParse(xData)
data<-xmlToList(doc)
a<-as.data.frame(unlist(data))
a<-dplyr::filter(a,grepl("http",`unlist(data)`) )
head(a)
```

Above code will give you a dataframe with list of all urls. I was just wondering you can also use "Xenu" url fetcher software to extract urls from website which are not included in sitemap.
Let me know in case you stuck somewhere in middle.